# How to choose the right normalization method for the right dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, normalization

There are several normalization methods to choose from. L1/L2 norm, z-score, min-max. Can anyone give some insights as to how to choose the proper normalization method for a dataset?

I didn't pay too much attention to normalization before, but I just got a small project where it's performance has been heavily affected not by parameters or choices of the ML algorithm but by the way I normalized the data. Kind of surprise to me. But this may be a common problem in practice. So, could anyone provide some good advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess it's very hard to find a good answer on this question. Normalization can be tricky. The goal is usually to treat all the features equal and avoid unfairly favoring one over the others. I think that's a really interesting question and it makes sense thinking about what assumptions go into these normalization methods and for what methods they make more/less sense. However this is a rather broad question and not so much about programming, but more about statistics, I guess.

Comment: Like you said, there are several, but there aren't thousands. Is there any reason why you can't just try them all (for example with a grid search in scikit-learn) and pick what works best?

Comment: @IVlad, Well, checking what works best is probably the ultimate solution in machine learning. In the end you will prefer the best working normalization method anyway. However I think it really make sense to understand what effects the normalization has on different methods.

Comment: This question should be migrated (not reposted, but moved) to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I understand stats may be a better place to ask answers, but how to migrate it to stats?

Comment: Please check this blog https://towardsdatascience.com/normalization-vs-standardization-quantitative-analysis-a91e8a79cebf