# How do we know if we have to go MinMax normalization or Mean normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I am trying to figure out how do I know when I should go for MinMax normalization and when I should go for Mean normalization?

Both of them do pretty much the same thing i.e. to restrict the dataset within a range. But how do I know which normalization is better for my dataset?

Please include examples as it will help in better understanding.

Comment: This is a lot like asking, When should I multiply by 7 vs by 2? "restrict the dataset within a range" is the definition of the generic term "normalization". You are just asking for introductions to normalization & these 2 specific normalization functions. That's too broad, unresearched & nevertheless frequently asked. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58175304/3404097 https://stackoverflow.com/q/29090749/3404097 Please ask 1 specific question re being stuck in solving some problem or following some presentation.

Comment: Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask], [help], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.